# Data Type Error when mapping in Azure Data Factories

Tags: database, azure-data-factory

While trying to map my fields for a data pipeline in Azure data factory, I run into this error.
Operation on target Copy Opportunities failed: ErrorCode=UserErrorSchemaMappingCannotInferSinkColumnType,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Data type of column 'MARKET' can't be inferred from 1st row of data, please specify its data type in mappings of copy activity or structure of DataSet.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

I am pretty certain the error is coming from the fact that I have multiple fields that use a JSON path which parses through my JSON with no specified data type. An example of that is below.

```
$..CUSTOMFIELDS[?(@.FIELD_NAME ==  'OPPORTUNITY_FIELD_1')][0].FIELD_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pipeline will consume only the same type of file then you can add mappings in your activity, that will tell you what datatype it is reading from your file